# Purging of transactional data in DB2

Tags: db2

We have existing table of size more than 130 TB we have to delete records in DB2 . Using delete statement would will hang the system. So one way is we can partition  the table month and year wise and then drop the partition one by one by using truncate or drop. Looking for a script which can create the partition and subsequently dropping.

Comment: EDIT your question, what operating-system runs your Db2-server? (Z/os, i-series,  Linux/Unix/Windows ).   What scripting tools are available at your site?

Comment: How many records should be deleted? Which rules? Provide more details if you expect good answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't partition the data within an existing table. You would need to move the data to a new ranged partitioned table.

If using Db2 LUW, and depending on your specific requirments, consider using `ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE` to move your data to a new table while keeping your table "on-line"

`ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE` has the ability to add Range Partitioning and/or Multi-Dimentional Clustering on the new table during the move.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055069.html

Still, a 130 TB table is very large, and you would be well advised to be carful in planning and testing such a movement.